# How to read Firebase document with auto generated document id using Javascript

Tags: javascript, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to read a single document from a Firebase collection using a variable that is populated with the document id. The document id is correct and the document exists in the collection. 
When I initiate the code using variable it seems that the read was successful but there is no data in the field I am interested in. (See Code below).

```js
db.collection("Pswref").doc(clpdocid).get().then((docRef) => { 
            const SingleRecord = docRef.data();
            console.log('yyyyyy - Great document found using fixed id for doc id ', docRef.data());
            console.log('yyyyyy - Title from database = >', SingleRecord.title);
            console.log('yyyyyy - Doc id ', clpdocid);
        })
        .catch((error) => { 
            console.error('yyyyyy - Error getting document ', error);
        });
```

However when I hard-code the document id in the get statement all is well and I can access the information needed. (See code below).

```js
db.collection("Pswref").doc("NoA6EBijcgsBIIOZCsWC").get().then((docRef) => { 
            const SingleRecord = docRef.data();
            console.log('xxxxxx - Great document found using fixed id for doc id ',docRef.data());
            console.log('xxxxxx - Title from database = >', SingleRecord.title);
        })
        .catch((error) => { 
            console.error('xxxxxx - Error getting document ', error);
        });
```

The image shows the console.log output as per the script. 
NB: You will note that the above queries are exactly the same accept for the doc id reference used and I get a different result as per the output generated via the console.

[image]

Can someone help me to understand why this might happen and what the solution might be?

I have commented on the line out giving the error and rerun so that the output in the console can show that the ‍‍`clpdocid` is actually correctly populated.(see snipped below)and then output on the new image.

```js
        db.collection("Pswref").doc(clpdocid).get().then((docRef) => { 
            const SingleRecord = docRef.data();
            console.log('yyyyyy - Great document found using fixed id for doc id ', docRef.data());
            //console.log('yyyyyy - Title from database = >', SingleRecord.title);
            console.log('yyyyyy - Doc id ', clpdocid);
        })
        .catch((error) => { 
            console.error('yyyyyy - Error getting document ', error);
        });
```

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

It's certainly the case that `clpdocid` doesn't actually contain the value you expect.  The `undefined` that you're printing from `docRer.data()` is proof that you've requested a document that doesn't exist, since the API documentation for [data()](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.DocumentSnapshot#data) says to expect undefined if the document was not found.

Try logging the value of `clpdocid` before the query to make sure you have the document ID you want.

Comment: Thank you Doug for responding. The clpdocid is actually populated with the document id. The reason why it does not appear is because the previous line fails with TypeError. I have commented that line out and now you can see clpdocid is populated correctly. (i will try to add the image again.

Comment: Once again. Thank you Doug. You were absolutely correct. Your comment made me to interrogate the string and found it contained a space at the end which made it an invalid document id. The field clpdocid is passed from the web page via the document.querySelector('#page') which worked just fine. However somehow added the space at the end. I removed the space using trim() and tested again. All is just fine thank you. You have greatly helped me.